# Can't get Leaflet.Editable working in Ionic/Leaflet App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, leaflet

Im building an app with ionic 1.0 and leaflet 0.7. I use a directive i have found in a plunker example (sadly i can't find the link anymore).

```
app.directive('leaflet', [
  function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        callback: "="
      },
      template: '<div></div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.callback(L.map(element[0]),  {editable: true});
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

In the HTML view it looks like this:

```
<leaflet height="100%" width="100%" callback="callback" id="map" ></leaflet>
```

So now i wanted to add this plugin called [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable/tree/leaflet0.7)  but i can't get it working.

I added it in the index.html like this:

```
<script src="lib/Leaflet.Editable-leaflet0.7/src/Leaflet.Editable.js"></script>
```

As you can see in the directive, i added also {editable: true} to the map options. But when i call for example the method enableEdit like this:

```
var circle =  L.circle([center.lat, center.lng], radius, {
        color: color.color,
        fillColor: color.fillColor,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: circleServis.getOpancity(),
        clickable: true
      }).addTo(map);

      circle.enableEdit();
```

The circle is shown on the map but not editable and i got the error: TypeError: circle.enableEdit is not a function. 
I really don't know what i have missed.

Update 14.03.2016
Found a working alterntive: 
[Leaflet.EditableHandlers](https://github.com/kartena/Leaflet.EditableHandlers)
Because i only need editable Circle i only tested L.CicleEditor.

Comment: Are you sure you are including Leaflet.js before Leaflet.Editable.js? Also the minimum required version of Leaflet is 0.7.3 (for Editable to work).

Comment: Yes i inculdet it after leaflet.js and i use leaflet.js version="0.7.7".

Comment: i included it after leaflet-geodesy this plugin works with no problem. But Editable is not working.